# Spring Architecture circular references and stackoverflows

Tags: java, spring, circular-reference

I have a question about how to avoid circular references and stackoverflows.

I have a User object and another News Object (with a User variable). I need a Comments object (that already has a News variable), but I also need that it has a reference to the User that has created the Comment.

If I create a User variable inside my Comment object I will have circular references and stackoverflows, so I think that I should only incluide a variable like userid in my Comment object.

So it could be that I'm right in my thinking or that I'm doing something wrong to get the stackoverflow errors. What would you do and why? If you can help, that will be great. Thanks.

This is the User...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@PasswordMatch(message = "{register.repeatpassword.mismatch}")
public class SiteUser {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "email", unique = true)
@Email(message = "{register.email.invalid}")
@NotBlank(message = "{register.email.invalid}")
private String email;

@Transient
@Size(min = 5, max = 15, message = "{register.password.size}")
private String plainPassword;

@Column(name = "password", length = 60)
private String password;

@Column(name = "enabled")
private Boolean enabled = false;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "firstname", length = 20)
@Size(min = 2, max = 20, message = "{register.firstname.size}")
private String firstname;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "surname", length = 25)
@Size(min = 2, max = 25, message = "{register.surname.size}")
private String surname;

@Transient
private String repeatPassword;

@Column(name = "role", length = 20)
private String role;

public SiteUser() {

}
```

Here comes the StatusUpdate(you can call it piece of news or article). It has a site user that is the one who has created that article.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "status_update")
public class StatusUpdate {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Size(min=5, max=255, message="{addstatus.title.size}")
@Column(name = "title")
private String title;

@Size(min=5, max=5000, message="{addstatus.text.size}")
@Column(name = "text")
private String text;

@Column(name = "added")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss")
private Date added;

@OneToOne(targetEntity = SiteUser.class)
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
private SiteUser siteUser;

@PrePersist
protected void onCreate() {
    if (added == null) {
        added = new Date();
    }
}

public StatusUpdate() {

}
```

And the Comment which can be done by any registered user, right? As you will notice the Comment has no User object to avoid circular references. And that is the question. How can avoid circular references if Autowired a User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "comments")
public class Comment {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "statusupdateid")
private StatusUpdate statusUpdate;

@Column(name = "commenttext")
private String commenttext;

@Column(name = "commentdate")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss")
private Date commentdate;

@Column(name = "userid")
private Long userid;


public Comment() {
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code please & explain?

Comment: Sure, you have all the information in this other post... [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43124674/how-to-show-related-objects-in-a-jstl-using-a-spring)  with my solution without using a User object in the Comment object. Thanks

Comment: Generally speaking circular references aren't a problem. Just `@JsonIgnore` one side of the pair when rendering, or use custom logic that has a max recursion depth or supports circular references eg with id fields.

Comment: I think you are right. I'm starting to find how to deal with them.