# How to show related objects in a jstl using a spring?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl

I have 3 objects: User, Comment and StatusUpdate(news). This is the User...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@PasswordMatch(message = "{register.repeatpassword.mismatch}")
public class SiteUser {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "email", unique = true)
@Email(message = "{register.email.invalid}")
@NotBlank(message = "{register.email.invalid}")
private String email;

@Transient
@Size(min = 5, max = 15, message = "{register.password.size}")
private String plainPassword;

@Column(name = "password", length = 60)
private String password;

@Column(name = "enabled")
private Boolean enabled = false;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "firstname", length = 20)
@Size(min = 2, max = 20, message = "{register.firstname.size}")
private String firstname;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "surname", length = 25)
@Size(min = 2, max = 25, message = "{register.surname.size}")
private String surname;

@Transient
private String repeatPassword;

@Column(name = "role", length = 20)
private String role;

public SiteUser() {

}
```

Here comes the StatusUpdate(you can call it piece of news or article). That has a site user that is the one who has created that article.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "status_update")
public class StatusUpdate {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Size(min=5, max=255, message="{addstatus.title.size}")
@Column(name = "title")
private String title;

@Size(min=5, max=5000, message="{addstatus.text.size}")
@Column(name = "text")
private String text;

@Column(name = "added")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss")
private Date added;

@OneToOne(targetEntity = SiteUser.class)
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
private SiteUser siteUser;

@PrePersist
protected void onCreate() {
    if (added == null) {
        added = new Date();
    }
}

public StatusUpdate() {

}
```

And the Comment which can be done by any registered user, right? As you will notice the Comment has no User object to avoid circular references.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "comments")
public class Comment {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "statusupdateid")
private StatusUpdate statusUpdate;

@Column(name = "commenttext")
private String commenttext;

@Column(name = "commentdate")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss")
private Date commentdate;

@Column(name = "userid")
private Long userid;


public Comment() {
}
```

Now I would like to show in my JSP an article, with all the related comments and each of them belong to a different user. Can I use a HashMap to relate the users and their comments? I do not see how.

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/viewonestatus/{id}")
public ModelAndView viewOneStatus(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {

    StatusUpdate status = statusUpdateService.get(id);

    int countComments = commentService.countStatusComments(status);

    List<Comment> comments = commentService.readAllComments(status);

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();

    for (Comment comment: comments){

        SiteUser user = userService.get(comment.getUserid());

        modelAndView.getModel().put("user", user);

    }

    modelAndView.getModel().put("commentscounter", countComments);
    modelAndView.getModel().put("status", status);
    modelAndView.getModel().put("comments", comments); //!!

    modelAndView.setViewName("app.viewonestatus");

    return modelAndView;
}
```

As you expect, when my JSP shows just one user (the last one) for all the comments, but I can not relate all the Comments with the corresponding Users

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <c:forEach var="comment" items="${comments}">
    <tr>
        <td>

    <div class="col-sm-2 sm-margin-bottom-40">
        <img class="img-responsive profile-img margin-bottom-20" id="profilePhotoImage" src="/profilephoto/${comment.userid}" />
    </div>
                                                <h4> 
            ${user.firstname} ${user.surname} 
            <span> 
              <!--  <span>${counterUserMap[comment.key]}</span> -->
            5 hours ago / <a href="#">Reply</a>
            </span>
        </h4>
        <p>
            <fmt:formatDate pattern="EEEE d MMMM y 'at' H:mm:ss" value="${comment.commentdate}" />
        </p>
        <p>${comment.commenttext}</p>
    </td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

I do not want to use JSON. I'm thinking about an anonymous class with all the stuff inside. Well, I'm open to your thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: Your user always showing the last one is because the code 
[modelAndView.getModel().put("user", user);] in the for loop.  It will always use the user from the last comment and send it to your JSP.  What is the reason on not using [${comment.user.firstname} ${comment.user.surname}].  That will give you the user who made the comment.

Comment: First, thanks for your help....Because the user is not part of the Comment object. It only has the user id. I did it that way to avoid stack overflows problems. (See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43077283/spring-architecture-circular-references-and-stackoverflows?noredirect=1#comment73237820_43077283)

Comment: Since you have the userid, you can link it using the @ManyToOne annotation.  This would be the most ideal way.  But if you really don't want to link them, then you can create a new `@Transient SiteUser siteUser;` attribute in Comment class.  And then in your for loop, you can use `comment.setSiteUser(user);` instead of `modelAndView.getModel().put("user", user);`.  Hope this will help.

Comment: I know, but I have lots of trouble with StackOverflows and circular references that I'm trying to avoid. May be I'm wrong and I should create the @ManyToOne annotation but the ToString method give a lot of problems that I do not know how to avoid. Did you see my other question? [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43077283/spring-architecture-circular-references-and-stackoverflows?noredirect=1#comment73237820_43077283  Will the Transient User avoid the StackOverflow problems?

Comment: After reading the post again, it seems like you should be able to get the user information from statusUpdate attribute within Comment class.  Can you try to use `${comment.statusUpdate.siteUser.firstname}`?

Comment: No, ${comment.statusUpdate.siteUser.firstname} does not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139524/discussion-between-mike-and-shokulei).

Answer (score 0):

Shokulei answer was the solution:

Since you have the userid, you can link it using the @ManyToOne annotation. This would be the most ideal way. But if you really don't want to link them, then you can create a new @Transient SiteUser siteUser; attribute in Comment class. And then in your for loop, you can use comment.setSiteUser(user); instead of modelAndView.getModel().put("user", user);. Hope this will help.

Thanks Shokulei